# Simple content management for a React app

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I have decided to develop a web site from scratch using React for practicing purposes. Some of the 'static' pages (just displaying some text, like "About Us" page) are managed by another person.

**Is there a more or less nice way to render text in my component from a file. So my teammate can change the contents any time she wants and push it independently.**

Also: **Is there a way to  read it with at least some formatting? Like with new lines?**

Note: 
Since we are on a very beginner level, I am not looking for a super solution. 
I have already seen how to read text from file with React. I am more interested in what is the best and simple solution to this kind of content management.

*I would really appreciate people not answer/comment if they only want to say that this is a stupid idea, without actually helping.*

Would really appreciate advice, suggestions and solutions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is present on a web server you can always get it with a simple HTTP get method. An example could be with an XMLHttpRequest. You can then read the response text, replace all `\n` with `<br/>` and insert it with `element.innerHTML` into your page so you have all the line breaks.

How to use XMLHttpRequest:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

If your file is on the same web server there should be no issues.
But if your file is hosted on another server than your page you could get some CORS problematics.

As you said, this is not a perfect solution but good enough for practicing HTTP Requests and requesting data from somewhere else.

EDIT: Replaced the Mozilla URL with the english one. I accidentally posted a german one first.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a file called **string.js** for example and create some constants like

```
export const LOREM = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt"

export const ABOUT = "We are very good friends"

export const WEB_NAME = "Our name"
```

and then from **another_file.js** call them like this.

```
import * as STRING from 'strings.js'

const element = (
    <h1>{STRING.WEB_NAME}</h1>
)
```